# gmailr text_body not included

Tags: r, gmail-api

I'm trying to send an email with gmailr, the e-mail sends fine but the body included in "text_body()" is missing.

When I remove attach_file() it however works.

```
mime() %>%
  to('email@email.com') %>%
  from('email@email.com') %>%
  subject(paste(Sys.Date()," Subject", sep = '')) %>%
  text_body('Body') %>%
  attach_file(paste(Sys.Date(),"Attachment.csv", sep = '')) %>%
  send_message()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/60) which is still unresolved.

A possible [workaround](https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/60#issuecomment-258552253) is to include the body a second time using `attach_part` like this:

```
mime() %>%
  to('email@email.com') %>%
  from('email@email.com') %>%
  subject(paste(Sys.Date()," Subject", sep = '')) %>%
  text_body('Body') %>%
  attach_part('Body') %>%
  attach_file(paste(Sys.Date(),"Attachment.csv", sep = '')) %>%
  send_message()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to improve this to both make it work and to improve its function. First, make it a function. Second, I've had success using the 'attach_part' function, but only once I've first made the 'mime.' You can also take the function out and simply use the code witin in.

```
msg <- "your message goes here"

prepare_and_send <- function(sender, recipient,
                             title, text,
                             attachment) {
  email <- mime() %>%
    to(recipient) %>%
    from(sender) %>%
    subject(title) %>%
    html_body(text) %>%
    attach_file(attachment, type = "html")
  email <- attach_part(email, msg) %>%
    send_message() 
}

# Put the above function to use.
prepare_and_send("sender@gmail", "to@gmail", "some subject",
                 "some text", "20558.html")
```